# Basic Probability: Is my application DeMorgan's Law wrong here?

Tags: probability

The question gives

P(A) = 1/3, P(B) = 1/4 and P(A⋂B) = 1/6 and asks for P(A<sup>C</sup>⋃B<sup>C</sup>)

I know the answer is 1/6, because

P(A<sup>C</sup>⋃B<sup>C</sup>) = 1 - P(A⋂B)

But I'm confused why DeMorgan's law here would give me 11/12, which is how I applied it:

P(A<sup>C</sup>⋃B<sup>C</sup>) = P(A<sup>C</sup>) + P(B<sup>C</sup>) - P(A<sup>C</sup>⋂B<sup>C</sup>)

= 3/4 + 2/3 - (2/3)*(3/4) = 11/12

What's wrong with my reasoning, and why is the solution the way it is?

Comment: You don't know if $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are stochastically dependent, since $P(A)P(B) \neq P(A\cap B)$. So, $A^c$ and $B^c$ are stochastically dependent as well and you have $P(A^c\cap B^c) \neq P(A^c)P(B^c)$.

Comment: pretty sure they're not independent because they don't satisfy independence condition: P(A⋂B) ≠ P(A)P(B) or 1/6 ≠ 1/3*1/4